# How to develop language syntax checker?

Tags: token, abstract-syntax-tree, lexical-analysis

I want to develop a syntax checker tool for my web-project. The aim is to analyze the ECMAScript 6 syntax.

I know, that there are some tools like BabelJs, where there exist such tools (but developed in NodeJs environment), but I want try to make such tool, because of getting new knowledge.

What shout I start to read, which books and articles?
I shall highlight what I want, I don't want compiler/interpreter, I just want a syntax checker.

Comment: I have found an interesting article series on the subject some time ago, I think it will be useful for you. Although it implements a subset of C in F#, the concepts could be applicable to pretty much every language out there: http://timjones.tw/blog/archive/2014/04/13/writing-a-minic-to-msil-compiler-in-fsharp-part-0-introduction

Comment: @Alejandro: it is worth noting that the author of that article only tries to explain his specific compiler, and that author admits he already read several technical books on compiling before he started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to:

- Know the ECMAScript 6 specification in excruciating detail;
- Build a lexer
- Build a parser

You need to learn about classic lexing and parsing, from a good source of the theory.   With that background you can think about building the lexer and parser for ECMAScript 6, which is what does the basic syntax checking.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing, especially the references.  Ideal is the Aho/Ullman/Sethi book on compiling.

Don't expect this to be easy (most parser-newbies make this error); parsing is actually a pretty complex topic.   Expect to spend a lot of effort to learn how to do this right.   You'll also need to learn how to build syntax error recovery into your parser if if is going to check for syntax and complain; techniques for doing this aren't as well documented/taught.

Loud hint: building lexers and parsers is a lot easier if you use lexer-generator and parser-generator tools.  You still need the compiler basics to understand what these do.

Here's a list of lexer ("regular expression") and parser generators to choose from: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_parser_generators

JavaScript has some features ("semicolon insertion") which make it singularly hard to parse by most conventional methods.  So what you will need to do is learn the theory to get the basics right, and then learn how to bend parsers to handle strange cases like JavaScript.

You'll also need that special parser bending to extract the JavaScript from the HTML pages that make up your "web project".